TypeError: product.features.map is not a function
  const [featureRatings, setFeatureRatings] = useState(() =>
    product.features.map((feature: { category: any }) => ({
      category: feature.category,
      rating: 0, // Default rating value
    }))
  );
const [processLifecycleRatings, setProcessLifecycleRatings] = useState(
 

enter image description here
help me to figure out what is going on here

Hi, The question would be complete if you could include product object as well - Its definition and scope.

The time your useStates callback is running products.features would be undefined. So you are not able to map it.
You could use optional chaining with a fallback empty array value.
You could use useEffect and wait till products.features is an array.
But would like to see more of your code before I give you a good solution
